# como puedo localizar y ejecutar un programa una vez instalado su .deb

Tags: linux, ubuntu

he instalado un programa a partir de su .deb con

```
sudo apt-get install ./program.deb
```

Mi problema es que una vez hecho esto no consigo encontrar el ejecutable para poder abrir el programa, no entiendo "a donde" va la instalación, y no me aparece en la lista de aplicaciones de menú de Ubuntu.
Soy muy novato en Linux y no se si esto es culpa del programa que me he instalado, o de que no se cómo ejecutarlo, os dejo el enlace del .deb del programa, es para la programación de FPGAs:

[Enlace de descarga del programa en cuestión](https://reference.digilentinc.com/reference/software/adept/start?redirect=1#software_downloads)

Answer (score 0):

Con el comando `dpkg -c <paquete.deb>` puedes listar los ficheros que te va a instalar un paquete.

```sh
➜  Baixades dpkg -c digilent.adept.utilities_2.4.1-amd64.deb 
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-12-11 02:12 ./
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-12-11 02:12 ./usr/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-12-11 02:12 ./usr/bin/
-rwxr-xr-x root/root     27720 2020-12-11 02:12 ./usr/bin/dadutil
-rwxr-xr-x root/root     25832 2020-12-11 02:12 ./usr/bin/djtgcfg
-rwxr-xr-x root/root     62344 2020-12-11 02:12 ./usr/bin/dsumecfg
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-12-11 02:12 ./usr/share/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-12-11 02:12 ./usr/share/digilent/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-12-11 02:12 ./usr/share/digilent/dsumecfg/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-12-11 02:12 ./usr/share/digilent/dsumecfg/bitstreams/
-rw-r--r-- root/root   2895364 2020-12-11 02:12 ./usr/share/digilent/dsumecfg/bitstreams/019_001_flash_config-1.bit
-rw-r--r-- root/root   2917568 2020-12-11 02:12 ./usr/share/digilent/dsumecfg/bitstreams/019_001_flash_config-2.bit
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-12-11 02:12 ./usr/share/doc/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-12-11 02:12 ./usr/share/doc/digilent.adept.utilities/
-rw-r--r-- root/root      5300 2020-12-11 02:12 ./usr/share/doc/digilent.adept.utilities/EULA
-rw-r--r-- root/root      2955 2020-12-11 02:12 ./usr/share/doc/digilent.adept.utilities/README.gz
-rw-r--r-- root/root       397 2020-12-11 02:12 ./usr/share/doc/digilent.adept.utilities/changelog.gz
-rw-r--r-- root/root      5511 2020-12-11 02:12 ./usr/share/doc/digilent.adept.utilities/copyright
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-12-11 02:12 ./usr/share/man/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-12-11 02:12 ./usr/share/man/man1/
-rw-r--r-- root/root      1890 2020-12-11 02:12 ./usr/share/man/man1/dadutil.1.gz
-rw-r--r-- root/root      1212 2020-12-11 02:12 ./usr/share/man/man1/djtgcfg.1.gz
-rw-r--r-- root/root      1566 2020-12-11 02:12 ./usr/share/man/man1/dsumecfg.1.gz
```

Se puede deducir que los ejecutables instalados son algunos de los siguientes:

```
-rwxr-xr-x root/root     27720 2020-12-11 02:12 ./usr/bin/dadutil
-rwxr-xr-x root/root     25832 2020-12-11 02:12 ./usr/bin/djtgcfg
-rwxr-xr-x root/root     62344 2020-12-11 02:12 ./usr/bin/dsumecfg
```

El directorio /usr/bin suele estar en el `PATH` por lo que con la ayuda del tabulador en cualquier directorio podrías ejecutarlos

Comment: he probado a correr esos 3 archivos con el comando run en el terminal, en todos me sale este error:                                                                                    ImportError: /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)

Comment: @rafaelayllón Tu pregunta ya ha sido contestada. Las normas del sitio son una pregunta por publicación. Si tienes una nueva pregunta, redacta una nueva publicación. Múltiples cuestiones dificultan que otros usuarios con el mismo problema encuentren esta publicación. Y si consideras que la respuesta ha solucionado tu problema, lo correcto es agradecerlo pulsando el *check* (`✓`). Un saludo.